# What is the recommended destination public IP for Cisco IP-SLA?

Tags: cisco, routing

I want to implement Cisco IP-SLA, but I am not sure what the destination IP I should use. Any recommendations or advice?

Comment: Also, be sure to consider the reliability, control and your ability to influence the destination you select.  The further away the destination, the less there is of any of these aspects.  

ICMP is often the first to drop during periods of congestion.  Do you have any ability to remedy issues with reachability with this destination?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a destination IP address that indicates that the link is fully functional.

Depending on your service requirements, that may be just the next hop on the ISP side, an important server you need to reach, or something similar.